# Is there an analytics api for adding a user group from google's marketing platform?

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have a large number of analytics properties and views that I want to manage access to through the google marketing platform user groups. I know I can add users individually by email, but I'm not finding a way to add a group by name or some sort of internal id.

I've scoured the analytics api reference documentation and I see lots of abilities for singular users, but nothing for groups.

Looking at something like this, just for user group management.

```
try:
  analytics.management().profileUserLinks().insert(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
      profileId='7654321',
      body={
          'permissions': {
              'local': [
                  'EDIT',
                  'MANAGE_USERS'
              ]
          },
          'userRef': {
              'email': 'liz@fakeemail.com'
          }
      }
  ).execute()
```